# stub getJSON function of JQuery using proxyquire and sinon.js

Tags: jquery, testing, mocha.js, sinon, proxyquire

I am trying to stub `getJSON`, `done` and `fail` function of jquery using sinon.js and `proxyquire` but always I am getting an error that .getJSON, done and fail is not function.

```
  const $ = require("jquery");
    const Progress = (() => {
      const getData = () => {
        return $.getJSON();
      };
      const showProgressBars = () => {
        getData()
          .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          })
          .fail(function (e) {
            console.log("error getting data.", e);
          });
      };
      return {
          getData,
          showProgressBars
      }
    })();
module.exports=Progress;
```

> Test

```
const proxyquire=require("proxyquire");
const sinon=require("sinon");
const expect=require("chai").expect;
describe("Progress", () => {
  it("should call getJSON", (done) => {
    const getJSONStub = sinon.stub();
    const jquerySpy = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
      return {
        getJSON: getJSONStub,
      
      };
    });
    const { getData } = proxyquire("../src/demo", {
      jquery: jquerySpy,
    });
    getData();
    expect(getJSONStub.callCount).to.be.eq(1);
    done();
  });
});
```

My requirement is to test these two functions but I am unable to do this. I already spent two days but unable to stub the getJSON, done and fail function.

Any help sould be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sinon.stub()` to stub `$.getJSON()` method and its returned value `JQuery.jqXHR` which has `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks. You can get the original callback passed in using `.callsFake()` method, after getting them, call these callbacks manually with mocked data or error.

You don't need to use `proxyquire` package.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const $ = require('jquery');

const Progress = (() => {
  const getData = () => {
    return $.getJSON();
  };
  const showProgressBars = () => {
    getData()
      .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .fail(function (e) {
        console.log('error getting data.', e);
      });
  };
  return {
    getData,
    showProgressBars,
  };
})();

module.exports = Progress;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const $ = require('jquery');
const { getData, showProgressBars } = require('./');

describe('Progress', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should call getJSON', async () => {
    const data = 'teresa teng';
    const getJSONStub = sinon.stub($, 'getJSON').resolves(data);
    const res = await getData();
    expect(res).to.be.equal('teresa teng');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getJSONStub);
  });

  it('should get data success', () => {
    const data = 'teresa teng';
    const mJqXHR = {
      done: sinon.stub().callsFake(function (callback) {
        callback(data);
        return this;
      }),
      fail: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const getJSONStub = sinon.stub($, 'getJSON').returns(mJqXHR);
    showProgressBars();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getJSONStub);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mJqXHR.done, sinon.match.func);
  });

  it('should handle error if get data fail', () => {
    const mErr = new Error('network');
    const mJqXHR = {
      done: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      fail: sinon.stub().callsFake(function (callback) {
        callback(mErr);
      }),
    };
    const getJSONStub = sinon.stub($, 'getJSON').returns(mJqXHR);
    showProgressBars();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getJSONStub);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mJqXHR.fail, sinon.match.func);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  Progress
    ✓ should call getJSON
teresa teng
    ✓ should get data success
error getting data. Error: network
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/67267452/index.test.js:34:18)
    at callFn (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:364:21)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:352:5)
    at Runner.runTest (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:677:10)
    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:801:12
    at next (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:594:14)
    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:604:7
    at next (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:486:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:572:5)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
    ✓ should handle error if get data fail


  3 passing (12ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: @santoshsingh You can use `proxyquire` for this case, but it's unnecessary. If you want to stub a standalone function from a package, use `proxyquire`.  `sinon.stub()` can stub a method inside an object or class.